# Does directory browsing have an accepted documented format?

Tags: java, html, http, jetty

We've implemented directory browsing in our web app. Our implementation uses the following three columns:

- `Name`
- `Last Modified`
- `Size`

It seems that across various web servers and other web apps there is a fourth column for `Description`. I have, personally, never seen this field populated, (and I've asked around other developers as well and none could say they have either). We chose to not display it as it added no value to us.

My question is -- is there an RFC that documents this, or some specific standard?

The reason I'm asking is that another (third-party) web application can integrate with ours and it breaks due to the number of columns it expects. (Funnily, in their directory browsing they also never seem to populate the `Description` field, but they are, nevertheless still displaying this column).

So... I'd like to know whose implementation is actually more correct and whether we have a bug, or they're expecting too much? (Of course, we could add an empty column to the table as well and uglify the HTML a bit, but is this really required?

Comment: There is no standard specification afaik, but I'd say the de-facto standard is what apache httpd `mod-autoindex` generates (optionally with `FancyIndexes`, and additionally in this case, the query parameters accepted for sorting columns). It's been available for a looong (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_autoindex.html) time....

Comment: Jetty's directory listing format was established in 1996, it has been updated slightly throughout the years (it can be styled with css now) but generally the output format (in html) hasn't changed much since those early years.  (The earliest commit I can find for apache httpd `mod_autoindex` is 1999)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt: Thanks for checking. We're using Jetty, but printing out the HTML ourselves. In Jetty, can the column be configured? Are all of them mandatory? And has anybody actually seen anything printed out in the `Description` column? I have been trying to find out, if there is something mentioned as a rule in an RFC, but, so far, my searches have yielded no reasonable results.